# Is my hosting company messing me up here: Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' (2)?

Tags: php, mysql, web-hosting

I use the hosting company aPlus.net, and I can't seem to get past a connection error I'm getting when trying to process some php to write database content to a webpage, and I am curious as to if this is because my database appears to not be on the same server as the entire rest of my hosting account, and if there is a way to resolve this in my code? This is my first attempt at writing PHP, and it would be good to know if my code is wrong, or if my hosting company is messing me up. (and either way, how to fix it)

Here's the code that's failing to pull from the database:

```
{
  $con = mysql_connect("localhost","2p5dq9vxmy240651","MY_PASSWORD");
  if (!$con)
  {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }
  mysql_select_db("felineasthma_2p5dq9vxmy240651", $con);
  $users_name = $_POST['name'];
  $users_comment = $_POST['requests'];
  $users_name = mysql_real_escape_string($users_name);
  $users_comment = mysql_real_escape_string($users_comment);
  $inputid = $_GET['id'];
  $query = "
  INSERT INTO `felineasthma_2p5dq9vxmy240651`.`submissions` (`id`,
   `name`, `requests`, `inputid`) VALUES (NULL, 
   '$users_name', '$users_comment', '$inputid');";
  mysql_query($query);
  echo "<h2>Your request has been processed, reload page.</h2>";
  mysql_close($con);
}
```

and here's some screen captures from inside my hosting account (links because I don't have enough posts here yet to upload images, sorry):

[felineasthma_2p5dq9vxmy240651 doesn't appear in my hosting account](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pBvlq.png)

[yet it clearly exists in MySQL Manager, but on a different server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O3TJr.png)

I was even more confused while making the user for this database, as the control panel didn't allow me to make a username, it just randomly assigned one. Help? Advice?

Comment: So why not try to connect to it on the server where it is instead of the server where it isn't? They give you the hostname to use.

Comment: Well, clearly your hosting company is messing you up. They do that because it helps them gain new customers. *Hey, let's screw with our users, and make all their stuff not work! They'll recommend us to everyone else! What a great idea!* is a great business plan.

Comment: @hobbs Can you explain to me how to do that? What do I need to change to do that? I tried putting the server listed in place of the localhost in the code, and it still failed.

Comment: @Ken White I'm not sure if you're being serious or attempting to make fun of my ignorance, but my question was genuine. I am new to writing PHP and I need to know if this is a problem with my code or if everything I do is seriously doomed to fail because of the hosting company placing my database on a different server. If you could clarify, that would be very helpful.

Comment: Just wanted to let the site know that I got everything working today, and no longer need help. I was apparently using depreciated php code, I found a more modern tutorial to learn PHP with, and now everything works.

Answer (score 0):

I found a more modern tutorial to learn PHP with, and now everything works, I just need to add security measures now. Here's the working code snippets, if anyone ever comes here asking the same questions.

here's the form action that places the entries into the database:

```
<?php
$servername = "sql5c40n.carrierzone.com";
$username = "my_username";
$password = "my_password";
$dbname = "my_database";
$users_name = $_POST['name'];
$users_request = $_POST['requests'];

// Create connection
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

$sql = "INSERT INTO submissions (name, requests)
VALUES ('$users_name', '$users_request')";

if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
    header("Location: clv.php");
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . mysqli_error($conn);
}

mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```

here's the include that puts the database entries onto the page:

```
<?php
$servername = "sql5c40n.carrierzone.com";
$username = "my_username";
$password = "my_password";
$dbname = "my_database";

// Create connection
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

$sql = "SELECT id, requests, name FROM submissions";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        echo "" . $row["requests"]. " - by " . $row["name"]. "<br>";
    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}

mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```